# Add reference from COM component

Tags: vb.net, com

I installed oracle 11g version on my system.

When I am adding a reference to my aplication from COM tab then I am not able to find "Oracle InProc server 5.0 Type Library". It is present in my colleague system at path C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0.3_32\Client\bin\oip11.tlb. 
This tlb file is also present in my system but not under COM tab in Add Reference.

When I am trying to add the file from Browse under Add Reference then I am getting the following error: "A reference to... could not be added.Please make sure the file is accessible, and that is a valid COM component."

What should I do to add this.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to use the COM reference rather than the .Net classes in Oracle.DataAccess.dll?  Refer to this link:  [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mismatch betweeen the oracle versions installed. So I have uninstalled and install again the oracle and the problem gets resolved. The component is available in the COM tab.